# Minimum path sum in a triangle (Project Euler 18 and 67) with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, dynamic-programming

[Project Euler 18](https://projecteuler.net/problem=18)
[Project Euler 67](https://projecteuler.net/problem=67)

As problem 67 is harder, I'll go with that one:

> By starting at the top of the triangle below and moving to adjacent
>   numbers on the row below, the maximum total from top to bottom is 23.
>
> ```
>              3
>             7 4
>            2 4 6
>           8 5 9 3
> ```
>
> That is, 3 + 7 + 4 + 9 = 23.
>
> Find the maximum total from top to bottom in [triangle.txt](https://projecteuler.net/project/resources/p067_triangle.txt) (right click
>   and 'Save Link/Target As...'), a 15K text file containing a triangle
>   with one-hundred rows.
>
> NOTE: This is a much more difficult version of Problem 18. It is not
>   possible to try every route to solve this problem, as there are 2^99
>   altogether! If you could check one trillion (10^12) routes every second
>   it would take over twenty billion years to check them all. There is an
>   efficient algorithm to solve it. ;o)

I solved this using dynamic programming. Here's my code:

```py
def max_triangle_sum(triangle, height):
    if height == 1:
        return triangle[0][0]

    dp = [[-1] * row_index for row_index in range(1, height + 1)]

    dp[0][0] = triangle[0][0]

    for i in range(1, height):
        dp[i][0] = dp[i-1][0] + triangle[i][0]
        dp[i][i] = dp[i-1][i-1] + triangle[i][-1]

        for j in range(1, i):
            dp[i][j] = max(dp[i - 1][j - 1], dp[i - 1][j]) + triangle[i][j]

    return max(dp[-1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    height = None

    while True:
        try:
            height = int(input('Please enter height of the triangle: '))

            if height <= 0:
                raise Exception('Height cannot be negative or 0')

            break

        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Error occurred: {e}')
            print()

    triangle = []

    for row_index in range(1, height + 1):
        while True:
            try:
                row = list(map(int, input(f'Please enter {row_index} space seperated integer(s): ').split()))

                if len(row) != row_index:
                    raise Exception(f'Exactly {row_index} numbers required')

                if any(number < 0 for number in row):
                    raise Exception(f'Numbers cannot be negative')

                triangle.append(row)

                break

            except Exception as e:
                print(f'Error occurred: {e}')
                print()

    print('The maximum triangle sum is: ')
    print(max_triangle_sum(triangle, height))
```

This runs quite fast, considering it would actually take 20 billion years (**If your computer can compute 10^12 operations in 1 second**) to solve using brute force. But still, it doesn't look that good

How do I improve this code?

Comment: Possibly helpful: [Project Euler # 67 Maximum path sum II (Bottom up) in Python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/225248/35991).

Comment: @MartinR Yes, very much. Thank you!

Comment: I managed to solve this problem in reasonable time with a [Djikstra algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

Comment: Yes, I know about Dijkstra's algorithm! Amazing idea! Can you please share you solution?

Comment: @Srivaths I'll be happy to share it as soon as I can. It is on a computer that's currently being repaired...

Comment: @OlivierRoche Sure, No problem

Comment: @Srivaths Meanwhile, I remembered that I did it as below, starting from the bottom of the triangle and computing maximum sum of heirs at each floor until I reached the top. Sorry for the loss of time...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Minor Cleanup

Contrary to @Graipher's opinion, I find your `max_triangle_sum` implementation is reasonably clear.  Although, I'm not sure I'd refer to it as dynamic programming; it is simply computing top-down the maximum sums for each row.

```
dp = [[-1] * row_index for row_index in range(1, height + 1)]
```

What does `row_index` mean?  It doesn't convey any meaning other than the index number of the row.  `[-1] * row_index` is ... mysterious.  `row_length` conveys meaning: it is length of the row, and `[-1] * row_length` tells the reader you have a row of `-1` values of a certain length.

What is the `-1` mean?  Where is it used?  This statement creates a triangular data structure, with `-1` at each cell, but only to allocate the structure.  The actual `-1` value is not used; it is unconditionally overwritten in the following code.  If you have a mistake in the following code, it might use this `-1` value, and quietly produce erroneous results.  If you used `None` instead of `-1`, if you ever accidentally used the value in a cell before it has been assigned, Python would raise an exception.

```
dp = [[None] * row_length for row_length in range(1, height + 1)]
```

Avoid negative indexing.

```
   dp[i][i] = dp[i-1][i-1] + triangle[i][-1]
```

Here, `triangle[i][-1]` is referring to the last cell on the ith row.  But the cells on the ith row from from `0` to `i`, so `triangle[i][-1]` simply means `triangle[i][i]`.    You are already assigning to `dp[i][i]`, so this gives the statement a nice symmetry:

```
   dp[i][i] = dp[i-1][i-1] + triangle[i][i]
```

You don't really need to pass `height` to `max_triangle_sum`: it can easily be computed as:

```
   height = len(triangle)
```

### Space

Because you are allocating `dp` to hold the values of sum of the paths to each cell of each row of the triangle, your solution takes \$O(N^2)\$ space to find the solution.

Consider these statements:

```
    dp[i][0] = dp[i-1][0] + triangle[i][0]
    dp[i][i] = dp[i-1][i-1] + triangle[i][-1]
    dp[i][j] = max(dp[i - 1][j - 1], dp[i - 1][j]) + triangle[i][j]
```

`dp[i][...]` only depends upon values in `d[i - 1][...]`.  This means you only need the previous `dp` row to compute the next `dp` row; you don't need the whole `dp` triangle structure, just two rows:

```
    curr = [triangle[0][0]]

    for i in range(1, height):

        prev = curr
        curr = [None] * (i + 1)

        curr[0] = prev[0] + triangle[i][0]
        curr[i] = prev[i - 1] + triangle[i][i]

        for j in range(1, i):
            curr[j] = max(prev[j - 1], prev[j]) + triangle[i][j]
```

As a bonus, this should be faster, since less indexing is being performed.

We've still got `triangle[i]` being indexed constantly.  We can eliminate that by iterating over the rows of `triangle` directly.  We'll use `enumerate()` so we keep the row index:

```
    for i, row in enumerate(triangle[1:], 1):

        prev = curr
        curr = [None] * (i + 1)

        curr[0] = prev[0] + row[0]
        curr[i] = prev[i - 1] + row[i]

        for j in range(1, i):
            curr[j] = max(prev[j - 1], prev[j]) + row[j]
```

That's a little cleaner, and a little faster.

Now the ugliest part having to handle the first and last value separately.  The problem is there is no value before the first element, and no value after the last element to compute the `max()` on.  But why isn't there?  Or more to the point, why can't there be?  If you padded the previous row with duplicated first and last values, you'd turn those special cases into the regular case of a value in the middle of the row:

```
    for i, row in enumerate(triangle[1:], 1):

        prev = [curr[0]] + curr + [curr[-1]]     # Duplicate first & last values
        curr = [None] * (i + 1)

        for j in range(0, i + 1):
            curr[j] = max(prev[j], prev[j + 1]) + row[j]
```

Note: I've had to change `prev[j-1]` and `prev[j]` to `prev[j]` and `prev[j + 1]` to account for the changed indices, due to the duplicated value at the start.

Now, we are filling in all the values of `curr` in a simple for loop.  This screams list comprehension.  No need to allocate the `curr` list ahead of time anymore.

```
    for i, row in enumerate(triangle[1:], 1):

        prev = [curr[0]] + curr + [curr[-1]]     # Duplicate first & last values
        curr = [max(prev[j], prev[j + 1]) + row[j] for j in range(0, i + 1) ]
```

But we're still doing a lot of indexing.  We've got `prev[j]`, and `row[j]` which are normalish indexes, and we've got `prev[j + 1]` which could be considered `adjusted_prev[j]` if we assigned `adjusted_prev` the values of `prev[1:]`.  Then, with all the values being retrieved by a simple `[j]` index, we can let Python do the indexing for us but turning the indexing into iteration.  Finally, since Python knows the number of values in the lists, we no longer need the `i` index:

```
    for row in triangle[1:]:

        prev = [curr[0]] + curr + [curr[-1]]     # Duplicate first & last values
        curr = [max(a, b) + x for a, b, x in zip(prev[:-1], prev[1:], row) ]
```

Since `prev[:-1]` gives us all the values of the `curr` with the first value duplicated, and `prev[1:]` gives us all the values of `curr` with the last value duplicated, we don't even need `prev`:

```
def max_triangle_sum(triangle):

    curr = [triangle[0][0]]

    for row in triangle[1:]:
        curr = [max(a, b) + x for a, b, x in zip([curr[0]] + curr, curr + [curr[-1]], row)]

    return max(curr)
```

The space requirement (ignoring `triangle`) is now \$O(N)\$, since only the previous row needs to be held in memory while the current row is being computed.

If it is guaranteed that the triangle only contains positive numbers, and since `max(0, x) == x` whenever `x` is positive, then instead of duplicating the first and last values, we could append and prepend a zero to each end.  This will allow us to remove the first row as a special case:

```
def max_triangle_sum(triangle):

    curr = []
    zero = [0]

    for row in triangle:
        curr = [max(a, b) + x for a, b, x in zip(zero + curr, curr + zero, row)]

    return max(curr)
```

Now, `triangle` doesn't even need to be held in memory.  Instead, an iterable object could be passed in, which could read the triangle in line by line on demand, further ensuring an \$O(N)\$ memory solution.

---

See other answers for great feedback on input sanitization, and reading the triangle data from a file.

Answer (score 6):

#### General

Since the problem gives the triangle as a text file, your program should probably be able to read that file. It would be quite a lot of work to input them manually, and when using the file like in `python triangle.py < triangle.txt` a first row with the number of lines needs to be added. This reading function can be quite simple:

```
def read_triangle(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        return [list(map(int, line.split())) for line in f]
```

#### Algorithm

As for the actual algorithm, I'm not quite sure what yours does. Which means that it is not very readable :). Not having any documentation, like a [`docstring`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) does not help either.

The easiest algorithm for this is a bottom up approach that reduces each line into the maximum sum reachable from the line above it.

```
def reduce_rows(row, row_below):
    """Reduces two consecutive rows to the maximum reachable sum from the top row."""
    return [max(row_below[i], row_below[i+1]) + row[i] for i in range(len(row))]

def max_sum(triangle):
    """Find the maximum sum reachable in the triangle."""
    row_below = triangle.pop()
    for row in reversed(triangle):
        row_below = reduce_rows(row, row_below)
        # print(row_below)
    return row_below[0]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    triangle = read_triangle("triangle.txt")
    print(max_sum(triangle))
```

#### Style

It's a good thing that you are already using a `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard. You also seem to be mostly following Python's official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). The only thing you could improve on that part is to reduce the number of blank lines. While some help the readability, parts that are logically connected should be in one block:

```
height = None
while True:
    try:
        height = int(input('Please enter height of the triangle: '))
        if height <= 0:
            raise Exception('Height cannot be negative or 0')
        break
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error occurred: {e}\n')

triangle = []
for row_index in range(1, height + 1):
    while True:
        try:
            row = list(map(int, input(f'Please enter {row_index} space seperated integer(s): ').split()))
            if len(row) != row_index:
                raise Exception(f'Exactly {row_index} numbers required')
            elif any(number < 0 for number in row):
                raise Exception(f'Numbers cannot be negative')
            else:
                triangle.append(row)
                break
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Error occurred: {e}\n')
```

I also put the separate exceptions and the happy path into an `if..elif..else` structure. This is not really needed (the other cases are never reachable if an exception is raised), but IMO it helps with readability. It also make it easier if at some point you decide that those should just print a message directly, instead of raising an exception that is immediately caught only to be printed. You could make those `print` statements directly, which would allow you to be more specific about the exception you expect. This makes it so that all other exceptions stop the program (as they should):

```
while True:
    try:
        height = int(input('Please enter height of the triangle: '))
    except ValueError as e:
        print(f'Error occurred: {e}\n')
    if height > 0:
        break
    else:
        print('Error occurred:  Height cannot be negative or 0')

triangle = []
for row_index in range(1, height + 1):
    while True:
        try:
            row = list(map(int, input(f'Please enter {row_index} space separated integer(s): ').split()))
        except ValueError as e:
            print(f'Error occurred: {e}\n')
        if len(row) != row_index:
            print(f'Error occurred:  Exactly {row_index} numbers required')
        elif any(number < 0 for number in row):
            print(f'Error occurred:  Numbers cannot be negative')
        else:
            triangle.append(row)
            break
```

#### Better user input

This is actually a good place to implement a function asking for user input and validating it. We need type validation and input validation here, so this should suffice:

```
def ask_user(message, type_=str, validate=None, non_valid_msg=""):
    while True:
        try:
            user_input = type_(input(message))
        except ValueError as e:
            print(f"Expected {type_}")
            continue
        if validate is not None:
            if validate(user_input):
                return user_input
            else:
                print(non_valid_msg)
        else:
            return user_input
```

Which makes your code a lot easier:

```
def list_of_int(s):
    return list(map(int, s.split()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    height = ask_user("Please enter height of the triangle: ", int,
                      lambda h: h > 0, "Height must be positive")
    triangle = [ask_user(f"Please enter {n} space separated integer(s): ", list_of_int,
                         lambda l: len(l) == n, f"Exactly {n} numbers required")
                for n in range(1, height + 1)]
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

## Don't raise generic exceptions

Avoid raising a generic Exception. To catch it, you'll have to catch all other more specific exceptions that subclass it.

Instead of raising `Exception` directly when the user inputs a bad height, consider raising a `RuntimeError`, or in a larger codebase, a custom subclass. Then, explicitly list all of the exceptions you expect to be raised in your `except` clause, e.g. `TyperError` and `RuntimeError`.

## Local variable names

The name `dp` isn't terribly informative as to what the list contains. Consider refactoring to something more descriptive.

## Using globals in time-senstive code

Project Euler problems tend to require some fairly intensive computations. It may be advisable to try extract as much performance as possible inside of critical portions of you code, such as within nested loops.

In your solution, all of the variables used after `if __name__ == '__main__'` are in fact *global variables*, which are [slower than local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241523/why-does-python-code-run-faster-in-a-function?noredirect=1&lq=1). For a mild performance boost, consider refactoring all of this code into a `main` function, which you may then call after the `__main__` guard:

```
def main():
    height = None
    ...
    print('The maximum triangle sum is: ')
    print(max_triangle_sum(triangle, height))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## Dummy values

You initially assign `height = None`, but there is no branch where `height` keeps that value. Therefore, it isn't *necessary* to initialize `height` at this time, since it is guaranteed to be given a value by the branches that follow.

Some organization encourage initializing variables early on with dummy values so that developers can immediately see what variables will be in play in the code that follows. Others *discourage* this practice, since it can give developers a false sense of what values a variable is expected to take on (e.g. will height be `None` later?). Whether you choice to initialize variables early with dummy values largely comes down to stylistic preferences.

## Documentation

You don't have any comments or docstrings in your code. These forms of documentation are extremely helpful for people who must read your code, which include both other developers as well you when you return to your code after working on another project for two months. Some basic conventions for writing docstrings are laid out in [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).